# Save russian text to pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf, cyrillic

I try save text to pdf via http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/ . But I have problem with saving russian text. In created pdf I see all latin letters and symbols. But russian letters I don't see. If write text like: "dfыва-:", in pdf I see: "df-:". I use font which have russian letters. If somebody had same problem, help please.
Code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.pdf");
doc.open();
BaseFont times = baseFont.createFont("/sdcard/test/TIMES.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
doc.add( new Paragraph("dfыва-:", new Font(times, 14) ) );
doc.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure your TIMES.TTF font has cyrillic characters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper encoding.

[This example](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=171&t=How_To_Write_Non_English_Text_To_PDF_Using_Java) will probably help you out.